# Is the order of two siblings implementation dependent?

Tags: xml, tree, documentation, xquery

If I have an XML document like this one:

```
<people>
    <person>
        <name> Mario </name>
        <age> 25 </age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name> Lucas </name>
        <age> 32 </age>
    </person>
</people>
```

Is always guaranteed that in the document order, Mario occurs before Lucas? so Lucas is always a following sibling of Mario, or it's implementation dependent?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than +1, because I really learned something new in regard to XML - And I am using it extensively for quite some time now. I am really surprised that it is not defined in the spec. However, as Michael Kay said, I have never encountered any processor which doesn't respect element order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Unlike with attributes, [where order is insignificant](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags) according to the [XML Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/):**

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or
>   empty-element tag is not significant.

***Element* order is *significant* in XML.**

However, surprisingly, the XML Recommendation makes no clear, explicit declaration regarding the significance of element order in general.  The grammar implies that element ordering is significant, but, unlike for attributes, there is no explicit statement regarding the significance of the order of elements.

There is the [following statement](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-element-content) in the case of [Element Type Declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#elemdecls):

> Definition: In this case, the constraint includes a **content model**, a
>   simple grammar governing the allowed types of the child elements and
>   the order in which they are allowed to appear.

But this is in reference to DTD element type declarations.  XSDs can similarly declare that ordering is significant (via `xsd:sequence`) or insignificant (via `xsd:all`) *for document validity*.  Order still may or may not matter to any given application -- that's up to the application.  <sub><sup>[Thanks to @C. M. Sperberg-McQueen for his helpful clarification between the difference of relevance to validity versus to any given application's purpose.]</sup></sub>

The significance of element ordering is addressed in [XML Information Set Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/) in [Section 2.2 Element Information Items](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#infoitem.element):

> An element information item has the following properties:
>
> [...]
>
> 4. **[children]** An ordered list of child information items, in document
>      order. This list contains element, processing instruction, unexpanded
>      entity reference, character, and comment information items, one for
>      each [element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#infoitem.element), processing instruction, reference to an unprocessed
>      external entity, data character, and comment appearing immediately
>      within the current element. If the element is empty, this list has no
>      members.

Comment: Be careful what you infer from xsd:all and xsd:sequence.  They mean that the order is, or is not constrained as a condition of validity; they say nothing about whether it "matters" or conveys information to an application.  If the purpose of an element is to provide a rank ordering of elements A, B, and C, an xsd:all requiring all three elements would be the correct content model; here, the ordering may be the *only* thing that matters to the application.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen:  I appreciate the clarification.  Answer updated.  Thank you.

Comment: It says that: "The relative order of siblings is the order in which they occur in the children property of their parent node". Since the document order is constrainted by some rules, but implementation dependent, I suppose that Mario occurs before Lucas just because all XML parsers parse the documents serially, but it's not required by the standard that Mario precedes Lucas, am I right?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, no, not so.  The XML specification is silent on the issue, but the XML infoset and the XPath data model are not silent.  Any XQuery implementation that showed a different order would be non-conformant (or using a non-standard mapping from XML to XDM).

Answer (score 3):

Although, as @kjhughes says, the XML Recommendation doesn't explicitly say so, all the APIs and tools built on top of XML assume that element order is significant, and is retained by the parser and reported to the application.

After all, you wouldn't want the paragraphs in a Word document randomly shuffled. (And it's probably because the XML designers were focussed on modelling documents that they failed to say anything: it was just so obvious it didn't need saying.)